# How to parse List<doube> in bundle from fragment to fragment?

Tags: android, fragment

I would like to parse data from fragment A to fragment B, but the only problem is, the data i want to parse is a List.

here is some code

```
  @Override
 public void OnEditItem(int position) {
    simpleActivity.toastMessage(context, "Edit Image : "+ position);
    Model selectedItem = mModel.get(position);
    final String selectedKey = selectedItem.getKey();
    final String selectedImage = selectedItem.getImagesUri();
    final String selecteDescriptions = selectedItem.getImageDescription();
    final String selectedImagesName = selectedItem.getImageNames();
    final List<Double> selectedDataset = selectedItem.getDataSet();

    InputFragment inputFragment = new InputFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("Label", selectedKey);
    bundle.putString("Image", selectedImage);
    bundle.putString("Descriptions", selecteDescriptions);
    bundle.putString("ImagesName", selectedImagesName);
    bundle.putParcelableArrayList("DataSet", selectedDataset);//this is where i got an error

    inputFragment.setArguments(bundle);
}
```

i got an error like this

```
Wrong 2nd argument type.Found 'java.util.ArrayList<Java.lang.Double>', required :'java.util.ArrayList<? extendes android.os.Parcelable>
```

how can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't make Double Parcelable, but you can create a class that contains your double and implement Parcelable in that class:

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class MyDouble implements Parcelable {
    public double myDouble;
    public MyDouble(double d){
        myDouble = d;
    }

    protected MyDouble(Parcel in) {
        myDouble = in.readDouble();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeDouble(myDouble);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<MyDouble> CREATOR = new Creator<MyDouble>() {
        @Override
        public MyDouble createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MyDouble(in);
        }

        @Override
        public MyDouble[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MyDouble[size];
        }
    };
}
```

and then you can use it like this:

```
final List<MyDouble> selectedDataset = selectedItem.getDataSet();
List<MyDouble> myDoubles = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Double d :
            selectedDataset) {
        myDoubles.add(new MyDouble(d));
    }
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("DataSet", myDoubles);
```

Comment: you should refactor your selectedItem.getDataSet() code to return a list of MyDouble instead a list of double

Comment: my calculated data is in Double[] thats why i try to change it to List<Double> here the snipped code my data, https://ibb.co/pRy4N0d, so how do i solve it? if im using MyDouble, it said require Double. I Cant chage it to MyDouble because opencv didnt provide object just provide Double

Comment: add this code after getting your data set:
'List<MyDouble> myDoubles = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Double d :
                selectedDataset) {
            myDoubles.add(new MyDouble(d));
        }'
and :
'bundle.putParcelableArrayList("DataSet", myDoubles);'

Comment: the d give me an error, cannot be applied to java.lang.DOuble

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194723/discussion-between-alon-aviram-and-appem).

Comment: Its Work, but, how can i get the data from the fragment B?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can create class Serializable:

```
class DoubleWrapper implements Serializable {
  double value;
}
```

Comment: how can i use this clas?

Comment: `bundle.putSerializable()`